# How do I find the available choices for anchorType in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-documentation

As a beginner I'm trying to learn to properly navigate Apple's API documentation while studying a tutorial book as assistance.  While following an example on programmatic constraints, I came across the following method:

```
let leadingConstraint = segmentedControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: <NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor>)
```

I've learned that angle brackets signify a generic.  However is this what Apple is implying by using angle brackets in this situation?  While searching the documentation on NSLayoutAnchor, I couldn't find "topAnchor" similar to how the following code has:

```
let topConstraint = segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
```

How can I find out what are the choices for the generic type called "AnchorType"?  Or am I looking at the context incorrectly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first example you give is invalid code (the lack of balanced angle brackets, for one). However, I think I understand what it might be trying to explain.

Apple's documentation for `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor` (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutxaxisanchor) has a similar example to your second.

In this the documentation explains that the types of the anchors need to match. In the line

```
cancelButton.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(saveButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0).active = true
```

both `leadingAnchor` and `trailingAnchor` are X axis anchors and the code is good.

In the second example

```
cancelButton.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(saveButton.topAnchor, constant: 8.0).active = true
```

`topAnchor` is a Y Axis anchor, so a warning is generated.

`NSLayoutXAxisAnchor` is derived from `NSLayoutAnchor`, so I think the first example you give is attempting to get across the idea that the parameter needs to be a `NSLayoutAnchor` that is actually a `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor`.

The documentation for `NSLayoutAnchor` (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutanchor) gives the possibilities:

- `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor`
- `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor`
- `NSLayoutDimension`